# REGEX_MATCH to match PG and not PG13 and vice versa

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I'm using bigquery and need to match PG for movies that are rated PG and PG13 for movies rated as such.

I'm struggling to find a good source for BQ's implementation of REGEX_MATCH and was hoping for some assistance.

So, to find PG I tried `SELECT REGEX_MATCH(PC_Rating, r'PG')` which finds the value fine but when I try to exclude PG13 as follows `SELECT REGEX_MATCH(PC_Rating,r'PG![0-9]{2}')` or `SELECT REGEX_MATCH(PC_Rating,r'PG^[0-9]{2}')` it doesn't match PG to true.

My column has Either PG or PG13*, where * can be one or many of the following [VSLNP].

Thanks.

Comment: Give a try to `SELECT REGEX_MATCH(PC_Rating, r'PG$')` command.

Comment: What does the $ character do. Thanks this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$` in the regex to do an exact match.

```
SELECT REGEX_MATCH(PC_Rating, r'PG$')
```

`r'PG$'` would match all the strings which ends with `PG`. You may do a further more exact match by adding start of the line anchor `^` at the start.

```
SELECT REGEX_MATCH(PC_Rating, r'^PG$')
```

Comment: Thanks, for interest's sake, what is the NOT operator. For example `!^PG` For does not start with PG. I've seen is as `!` and `^`

Comment: "For does not start with PG", `^(?!PG)`, don't know whether GBQ supports negative lookahead or not..

Answer (score 1):

To match "PG" in the list of ratings you can use below. 
It has no dependency on where in the list this rating is (start, end or in the middle ...)

```
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(PC_Rating, r"\bPG\b")
```

Note, REGEXP_MATCH is relatively expensive function  - so if the "RG" value is the only value you expect in the column - you rather should use

```
WHERE PC_Rating = "PG"
```

And to match `PG13*, where * can be one or many of the following [VSLNP]` you can use below

```
WHERE REGEXP_MATCH(PC_Rating, r"\bPG13(V|S|L|N|P)*\b")
```